# nginx reverse proxy between 2 https servers

Tags: nginx, heroku, nginx-config

I'm a bit new to using nginx so I'm likely missing something obvious. I'm trying to create an nginx server that will reverse proxy to a set of web servers that use https.

I've been able to get it to work with one server list this:

```
server {
    listen $PORT;
    server_name <nginx server>.herokuapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://<server1>.herokuapp.com;
    }
}
```

However, as soon I try to add in the 'upstream' configuration element it no longer works.

```
upstream backend {    
    server <server1>.herokuapp.com;
}

server {
    listen $PORT;
    server_name <nginx server>.herokuapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://backend;
    }
}
```

I've tried adding in 443, but that also fails.

```
upstream backend {    
    server <server1>.herokuapp.com:443;
}

server {
    listen $PORT;
    server_name <nginx server>.herokuapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://backend;
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not setting the Host header, so the default value `$proxy_host` is being used. In the versions that do not work, this is set to the literal text "backend", which is probably rejected by the upstream server. You may find it's simplest for you to use your first approach.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I wanted to actually have multiple services in 'upstream backend'. So the first approach won't be able to handle this. e.g.
```
upstream backend {    
    server <server1>.herokuapp.com;
    server <server2>.herokuapp.com;
}

```

Comment: This is the example that I followed btw. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

Comment: You can use an `upstream` block, but you will need to set the Host header (e.g. `proxy_set_header Host example.org;`) to something that both of your upstream servers will respond to.

Comment: How do I figure out what that header will be?